# Using Pandoc's Webtex URI for Bigger Latex Equations

Tags: google-visualization, pandoc

I'm trying to increase the size of the LaTeX equations that are output by Pandoc using the Google Charts API through using the following command in Terminal:

```
pandoc -s --webtex=http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chs=500&chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&chl= --self-contained test.Rmd -o test.html
```

However, there is no change to the output of the LaTeX code (it doesn't increase in size), in fact when I look at the rendered html file segment (where `$\frac{1}{x}$` was) the image source tag I see is:

```
<img style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D" alt="\frac{1}{x}" title="\frac{1}{x}" />
```

Where am I using the `--webtex[=URL]` incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

I found that on the command line all I had to do was escape the `&` (ampersand) symbols. So to get this to work all I had to do was this:

```
pandoc -s --webtex=http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx\&chs=500\&chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00\&chl= --self-contained test.Rmd -o test.html
```